# uniform convergence $\sum _{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{\log (1+nx)}{nx^n}$ on $x \in (1,\infty)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

How could I prove that  $\sum _{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{\log (1+nx)}{nx^n}$ is not uniformly convergent on an interval $I=(1,+\infty)$?
So far I have been thinking of proving that $f_n(x)=\frac{\log (1+nx)}{nx^n}$ does not uniformly converge on the interval, which leads me to finding  $\lim _{n\to \infty}\sup_{x>1} \frac{\log (1+nx)}{nx^n}$. But there could be a nicer way.

Comment: What is $$\sup_{x\in(0,+\infty)}\frac{\log(1+nx)}{nx^n}$$ already?

Comment: That is $\infty$ oh I am sorry, the interval $I$ should have been $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: What do you mean not uniformly convergent?
$$\sum _{n=0} ^{\infty} \left|\frac{\log (1+nx)}{nx^n}\right| \leq \sum _{n=0} ^{\infty} \left|\frac{nx}{nx^n}\right| = \sum _{n=0} ^{\infty} \left|x^{-n+1} \right|$$ which is uniformly convergent in your interval.

Comment: When $x=1+\epsilon$, the bounding series is $\frac{1+\epsilon}{\epsilon}$. Uniform convergence looks chancy for $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @Diger You seem to be using Weierstrass M incorrectly.

Comment: @zhw: What do you mean? So $\log(1+x)\leq x$ for $x\in (0,\infty)$ is wrong?

Comment: @herb steinberg: So you are saying because as $x\rightarrow 1$ the function $\frac{1}{1-x}$ blows up, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$ is not uniformly convergent for any $x<1$?

Comment: I guess I'm mistaken in the sense that the geometric series is not uniformly convergent, but only locally uniformly convergent, right?

Comment: @Diger: $\sum _{i=0}^{n} x^i = \frac {x^{n+1}-1} {x-1}$ so $\sup_{0<x<1} |\frac {x^{n+1}-1} {x-1}-\frac{1}{1-x}|=\sup_{0<x<1} |\frac {1} {x-1}x^{n+1}|=\infty$ so $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} x^n $$ cannot be uniformly convergent on $[0,1)$.

Comment: @Diger  Are you sure you understand what uniform convergence means?  "Locally uniform convergent"????  (Strange term)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141882/uniform-convergence-vs-local-uniform-convergence-for-sequences-of-complex-funct

That is what I meant! I mixed it up, sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to see that each summand in the series is bounded on $(1,\infty).$ If the series were uniformly convergent on $(1,\infty),$ then the series would sum to a bounded function there.

To show this fails, note that

$$\ln(1+nx) > \ln (nx) = \ln n + \ln x > \ln n.$$

Thus our series is bounded below by

$$\tag 1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{nx^n}.$$

We're done if we show that as $x\to 1^+,$ $(1)\to \infty.$ That is easy to do, since $\sum (\ln n)/n=\infty.$

Comment: I understand that if the series is uniformly convergent on $(1,\infty)$ it's partial sums have to behave like a Cauchy sequence (the first inequality). The second inequality follows from the sequence $$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$$ being increasing and convergent towards e. In the last chain of inequalities, where exactly does $$\sum _{n=N}^{2N} \frac{1}{n}>\int _{N}^{2N} \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}x$$ follow from? I can visualize it but I am not sure why it applies.

Comment: $1/x$ is $\le 1/N$ on $[N,N+1],$ $\le 1/(N+1)$ on $[N+1,N+2],$  ...

Comment: @Kryštof I added a new proof, which I think is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

For large enough $N$ consider the inequalities
\begin{align}
x^{-N-1}\,\Phi\left(\frac{1}{x},1,N+1\right) &= x^{-N-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{-n}}{N+1+n}=\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{x^{-n}}{n} \\
&\leq \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{\log(1+nx)}{nx^n} \leq \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty x^{-n+1} = \frac{x^{-N}}{1-\frac{1}{x}}
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ is the Lerch-Zeta function which has the expansion
$$
\Phi(z,s,a)=\frac1{2\,a^s}+\frac{\log^{s-1}\dfrac1z}{z^a}\,\Gamma(1-s,a\log\dfrac1z)+\frac2{a^{s-1}}\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\sin(s\arctan t-a\,t\log z)}{(1+t^2)^{s/2}\cdot (\mathrm{e}^{2\,\pi\,a\,t}-1)}\,\mathrm dt
$$
i.e. for $z=\frac{1}{x}$, $s=1$ and $a=N+1$
$$
\Phi\left(\frac{1}{x},1,N+1\right) = \frac{1}{2(N+1)} - x^{N+1} \, {\rm Li}\left(x^{-N-1}\right) + 2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin\left(\arctan(t) - t\log\left(x^{-N-1}\right)\right)}{\left(e^{2\pi t(N+1)}-1\right)\sqrt{1+t^2}} \, {\rm d}t \, .
$$
About $x=1$ the logarithmic integral is
$$
{\rm Li}\left(x^{-N-1}\right) = {\rm Ei}\left(\log\left(x^{-N-1}\right)\right) = - {\rm Ei}_1\left(-\log\left(x^{-N-1}\right)\right) = \gamma + \log(N+1) + \log(x-1) + {\cal O}\left(x-1\right)
$$
in fact for $x>1$ we have
$$
\gamma + \log(N+1) + \log(x-1) \geq {\rm Li}\left(x^{-N-1}\right) \, .
$$
For $x \in (1,2)$ the last integral is bounded by some constant $C$ and choose the minimal value on $(1,2)$.

Take any $\epsilon >0$ and $x_0 \in (1,2)$ and set
$$
N=\left\lceil \frac{\log\left(\epsilon\left(1-\frac{1}{x_0}\right)\right)}{-\log \left( x_0 \right)} \right\rceil
$$
for then we have
$$
\sum_{n=m}^\infty \frac{\log(1+nx_0)}{nx_0^n} < \epsilon \qquad \forall m\geq N+1 \, .
$$

Now take $x\in(1,2)$ sufficiently smaller $x_0$ when we have
$$
x^{-N-1} \left(\frac{1}{2(N+1)} + C \right) - \gamma - \log(N+1) - \log(x-1) \leq x^{-N-1}\,\Phi\left(\frac{1}{x},1,N+1\right)
$$
for the LHS. Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{\log(1+nx')}{nx'^n} > \epsilon \qquad \forall x'\leq x \, .
$$

Comment: Whoever didn't even have time to read, obviously had time to vote...